# Creating copy of UIImageView in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am creating an app in which i draw something over imageview using a sublayer function, now i want to create a copy of that image view (over which there is everything like sublayers and image) so that my original imageview don't get effected while accessing imageview for some other purposes. Is it possible to create a copy of image view containing all the contents and use that imageview again and again for different purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're trying to copy only the contained UIImage, or an image of all the layers. Examples for both:

```
import UIKit

// Original UIImageView
var imageView = UIImageView()

// Copying image into new UIImageView
var _imageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)

// Rendering everything inside the UIImageView into a new UIImageView
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_imageView.bounds.size, _imageView.opaque, 0.0);
_imageView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
let allLayersImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
var __imageView = UIImageView(image: allLayersImage)
```